# Euler angles, how many rotations do I need to make to get the original vector back?

Tags: geometry, rotations

I wrote a program for rotating vectors about three Euler angles, according to this definition of the rotation matrix: http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C4%85ty_Eulera . When testing it, I made it rotate the given vector by the angles $\frac{2 \pi}{3}, \frac{2 \pi}{4}, \frac{2 \pi}{5}$ a total of $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 = 60$ times, thinking this would get me the original vector back, but it doesn't, and I don't know why. I checked the code and it looks alright, so it seems to me the fallacy is mathematical, but I don't understand what's wrong. I saw on the wiki page that the last angle was meant to be from $[0,\pi)$, but replacing $ \frac{2 \pi}{5}$ with  $\frac{\pi}{5}$ also doesn't work.

[image: This is the matrix I'm using.]

Comment: For those of us who can't read polish, here's the english version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Comment: I linked that one on purpose, since the english wiki lists tons of conventions for the rotation matrix. I use this particular link because there's only one rotation matrix given there, $A=A_1 A_2 A_3$, at the bottom of the page.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to just link that rotation matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotations don't generally commute. So if A, B, C are your three rotations about the three axes,

$$A^3=B^4=C^5=I$$
but
$$(CBA)^{60} = (CBA)(CBA)(CBA)\ldots \neq C^{60}B^{60}A^{60}.$$

Comment: Well, that explains it. So I will have to rotate seperately then. Thanks!

Comment: Euler angles are notoriously subject to gimball lock.  If your solution doesn't specifically require them, you may want to use a forward + up vector approach.